# Inner Join 3 tables pl/sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically i want to inner join 3 tables and the case is understood by the query itself as follows.

Tables:

```
A has 2 columns column 1 and column 2 
B has 2 columns column 3 and column 4
C has 3 columns column 5,column 6 and column 7
```

Query:

```
select A.column1, C.Count(C.column6) 
from table1 as A inner join table3 as C on A.column2 = C.column5 
inner join table2 as B on C.column5 = B.column4 and column3 = 'abcd' 
where column7 > NOW() - Interval '30 days' 
group by C.column5 
order by C.count(column5) desc
```

But I am getting an error schema C does not exist

Why is this happening? Any mistake with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the alias `C` where you should not, with the `count` function. This:

```
C.Count(C.column6)
```

should be:

```
Count(C.column6)
```

and the same change applies in the `order by` clause (which might be counting the wrong column - should it not be column6?):

`order by C.count(column5) desc` **->** `order by count(column6) desc`

Also: you should reference all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause, so it should probably be `group by A.column1`